# Python: variable initialization and for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, initialization

I have a list of `int` ranging from `0` to `99`, for instance `center_nodes=[51,52]`, and I want to perform a simple operation:

Take the first element, `center_nodes[0]`, get its first figure, `first=str(center_nodes[0])[0]`, and then add an `int` to it based on the figure itself.

Example: if `first=5`, then `result=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)`. In this case it should yield `56`.

I wrote a piece of code to do this but I always get `0`. There must be some very stupid mistake I have made, and I suspect it lies in the initialization of the `result` variable, which in the script is called `grid_coord`.

My attempt:

```
#code block to compute the center_nodes[] list
#here comes my script:
first=str(center_nodes[0])[0] #Get the first figure of element 0 of center_nodes
print('first figure: '+str(first))
grid_coord=None
if len(str(center_nodes[0]))==1: #Check if center_nodes[0] is in the 0-9 range
    grid_coord=int(first)
    print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
elif len(str(center_nodes[0]))==2: #Check if center_nodes[0] is in the 10-99 range
    if first==1: #Checks the first digit of center_nodes[0] and then adds it to int(center_nodes[0])
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==2: #Check the second digit...
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==3: #Check the third digit...
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==4: #4th
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==5: #5th
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==6: #6th
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==7: #7th
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==8: #8th
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
    if first==9: #9th and last
        grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
        print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
```

For `center_nodes=[51,52]`, I should get `grid_coord=56`, but I get `grid_coord=0` instead. What should I change?

Comment: I am not able to find giant_coord in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The variable that is wrongly computed is called `grid_coord`. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first=str(center_nodes[0])[0] #Get the first figure of element 0 of center_nodes
grid_coord=None
if len(str(center_nodes[0]))==1: #Check if center_nodes[0] is in the 0-9 range
    grid_coord=int(first)
    print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
elif len(str(center_nodes[0]))==2: #Check if center_nodes[0] is in the 10-99 range
    grid_coord=int(center_nodes[0])+int(first)
    print('Grid coord for center giant comp is: '+str(grid_coord))
```

Comment: Yes you are converting the first digit to string before storing it in first. So on comparing you have to compare it using string comparison.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way of "compressing" this piece of code to make it more general and efficient?

Comment: All the if's in elif block are essentially the same. You can work with first >= 1 and first <= 9. Only one if

Comment: I guess if I change `elif len(str(center_nodes[0]))==2:` to `elif len(str(center_nodes[0]))>=2:`, I could also include numbers up to `9999`. Correct?

Comment: It'll. But it'll only consider the first two digit of each number.

Comment: Why? Doesn't this line `first=str(center_nodes[0])[0]` always consider the very first digit only?

Comment: Then why did you say it will "only consider the first two digit of each number"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95237/discussion-between-francesco-castellani-and-user2393267).

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct you need smthng like:

```
l = [51, 52, 83]

for item in l:
    newItem = int(str(item)[0]) + item
    print newItemt
```

Comment: First, you need to check `len(l[0])`, to account for situations where `int(l[0])<10`. Also, you only need focusing on `l[0]`.